# Synaptic menu bar action icons inconsistent

Tags: icons, xfce, synaptic, menu-bar, numix

[image: synaptic-menu-bar]

Hi all, two of the action icons - "Mark All Upgrades" and "Apply" - on my Synaptic package manager menu bar are different. I would like them to be like the "Reload", "Properties" and "Search" buttons. Please see the attached image. Can anyone help? I'm running Ubuntu 16.04, XFCE, with Numix-Circle icons. The desktop theme is Zukitwo.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Either use a different icon theme, or replace the not wanted icons with the ones you like inside `/usr/share/icons/{numix-circle?}`. Assuming the icons you wish to have are in `/home/{username}/`the command would be `sudo cp ~/{new icon}.png /usr/share/{icon-theme}/{old icon}.png` - this has to be done for each icon you'd like to exchange.